# How to convert an object into a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object **request** which is as follows:-

```
var request = {
  itemname1: 'Adidas T-Shirt',
  category1: 'T-Shirt',
  brand1: 'Adidas',
  size1: 'M',
  amount1: '599',
  itemname2: 'Jockey Vest',
  category2: 'Vest',
  brand2: 'Jockey',
  size2: 'S',
  amount2: '299'
}
```

I want to convert it into a nested array as this:-

```
insert_values = [ ['Adidas T-Shirt','T-Shirt','Adidas','M','599'], ['Jockey Vest','Vest','Jockey','S','299'] ]
```

This nested array will be passed into the mysql database for bulk inserts. I am not much familiar with the **forEach** method, so I couldn't properly loop through the request object by index. How can I do this?

Comment: _"so I couldn't properly loop through the request object"_ - Because an object has no `.forEach()` method... - What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to get an array of objects as the `request`. Multiple objects stuffed into one object with incrementing keys is a bad structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do something like use `Object.entries` to convert the object to an array, reduce the array to a new one by inferring the index from the number at the end of each key:

```js
const data = Object.entries({
  itemname1: 'Adidas T-Shirt',
  category1: 'T-Shirt',
  brand1: 'Adidas',
  size1: 'M',
  amount1: '599',
  itemname2: 'Jockey Vest',
  category2: 'Vest',
  brand2: 'Jockey',
  size2: 'S',
  amount2: '299'
}).reduce((carry, [key, value]) => {
    const [text] = key.split(/\d+/);
    const index = key.substring(text.length) - 1;
    if (!Array.isArray(carry[index])) carry[index] = [];
    carry[index].push(value);
    return carry;
}, []);

console.log(data);
```